# Find and classify all critical points of $\ \ \ x'=e^{-x}. \ $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find and classify all critical points of $\ \ \ x'=e^{-x}. \ $

Find $  \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} x(t) $ for $ x(0)=0 $ initial condition.

**Answer:**

$$ x'(t)=e^{-x} \neq 0 \text{ for any } x. $$

So there is no critical points.

Now, integrating , we get

$$ e^x=t+c $$

using I.C. $ x(0)=0 $ , we get

$$ c=1 $$

So ,  $ \ e^x=1+t $

or, $ x(t)=\log (1+t) $ , which is an increasing function for $ t>0 $.

So, $ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty } x(t)= \infty $.

**Am I right ? Any confirmation is there ?**

Comment: @space:  Are you sure this is right?  I agree there are no critical points, but the differential equation is not $y' = e^{-x}$, but instead is $x' = e^{-x}$.  Isn't the solution more complicated?

Comment: yes some calculation mistake was there , I now corrected it . please check and tell me whether it is correct .

Comment: @JasonDeVito whoops, sorry OP

Comment: Now it looks good to me!

Comment: Although I'm hesitant to say so now that I screwed it up before, I think you're right now. The only problem I see is you wrote $\lim_{x\to \infty}x(t)$ rather than $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)$

Comment: It is $ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty } x(t) $

Comment: The answer to the title is that there is no fixed point, **obviously**, since $x'=f(x)$ with $f\ne0$ everywhere. Furthermore, $f>0$ everywhere hence every solution is increasing with limit $+\infty$. All this is a general theorem in your notes.